# C++ Function Skipping Code

Tags: c++, global-variables

I have written the following code, which compiles fine. However, when I run it, it skips the `getline(cin, p[x]);` the second time the function is called. Can anyone tell me why?

Here's the code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "simpio.h"
#include "strlib.h"
#include "iostream.h" 
#include "random.h"

int Hp[2], Atk[2], Ddg[2];
std::string p[2];

void player(int x)
{
    cout << "Player name: ";
    getline(cin, p[x]);
    cout << "\tHp: ";
    cin >> Hp[x];
    cout << "\tAtk: ";
    cin >> Atk[x];
    cout << "\tDdg: ";
    cin >> Ddg[x];
}

main()
{
    string go;

    player(0);
    player(1);

    cout << "Go? (Yes/No): ";
    cin >> go;
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: You stepped through the code in the debugger?  You can't just "skip" a line of code w/o some condition.

Comment: There are so many duplicates of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=getline+skipping

Comment: Also, I'd recommend not mixing `getline` and `cin>>` together like that when it's clearly for same purpose. Flushing streams can be a bit tricky for a beginner, but `getline` does that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cin` stream isn't flushed from first use and `getline` assumes input has been done already. You can flush it using:

```
cin.clear(); //clear any possible bits
cin.ignore(); //throw away whatever is there left in the stream
```

Answer (score 3):

I think its because there is still a `\n` left in the input stream.
Try a `cin.ignore()` before using `getline`. I hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for the up votes. I am new here and love being up voted :D.

Comment: Try using code elements in your answers to distinguish natural language from programming language. I did that for you this time.

Comment: Ya, saw that. Thanks. Will remember for next time.

Answer (score 2):

The code appears to be "skipping" the second call to `std::getline()` because the previous call to `player()` performed an extraction through `std::cin` that left a newline in the stream. `std::getline()` only reads characters until the next newline - so what appears to be skipping is just `std::getline()` failing to input characters because of the residual newline.

The solution is to clear the newline using `std::ws`:

```
std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, p[x]);
```